# Mockito test for MultipartFile.transferto() in Service layer

Tags: java, spring, mockito

```java
public void saveFile(MultipartFile file , int id) throws IOException {
    String date = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("-yyMMddHHmmss"));
    String destination = goldenFileLocation + "/"  + file.getOriginalFilename() + date;
    file.transferTo(new File(destination));
}
```

I need to write a Mockito test for the above service layer code. I have the below code but not sure how to test if the file exists in the mentioned location.

```java
@Test
public void testSaveFile() throws IOException {
    MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("pdf", "response.pdf", "multipart/form-data", "data".getBytes());
    saveFile(firstFile,1);

    //check if file got stored in the mentioned location
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what this has to do with Mockito.  The [MockMultipartFile class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html) is part of Spring, it's not part of Mockito.